# Split datatable into multiple arrays based on column value in C#

Tags: c#

I am having a datatable with multiple records having different key values. For example, a key 34 has multiple rows and some 35 has multiple rows. I need to split this key into separate arrays based on the column value.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please provide a better explanation and example

Answer (score 1):

```
var rows34 = (from r in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
             where r.Field<int>("KeyColumn") == 34
             select r).ToArray();

var KeyGroups = from r in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                group r by r.Field<int>("KeyColumn") into g
                select g;
```